# Intemittent Cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: windows, object, com, registry

Everything was working fine, and then our code starts throwing:

Cannot create ActiveX component when we try to create a com object.

We reboot the server a couple of times and it goes away

Then after a while it comes back

This is driving us nuts.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You haven't told us anything that can help you. What OS?  What specific API call is failing?  What ActiveX control?  What type of app (client or server)?  What type of debugging have you done yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize that the question was vague.  However we had no clue what was causing the problem so what facts would have been relevant?

At any rate it turns out we have two web apps running under IIS, both are trying to create ActiveX components.  As soon as we turn one of the web apps off the problem goes away.

After we verified this behavior, we tried calling some simple ActiveX components (like excel).  Lo and behold exactly the same behavior as long as there are more than two web apps running.

Our solution for now is to host the second web app elsewhere.