# System.Exception: 'Cannot create ActiveX component.' Coreldraw

Tags: vb.net, com, coreldraw

I'm getting a System.Exception: 'Cannot create ActiveX component.' on the corelApp = CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application")

I have the proper reference libraries imported and the excel.application line works fine. What would prevent the system from creating a CorelDraw.Application object?

I have explored the problem here [Intemittent Cannot create ActiveX component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585358/intemittent-cannot-create-activex-component)
and here
[ASP.NET Cannot create ActiveX component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847444/asp-net-cannot-create-activex-component) to no avail. And I have explored the CorelDRAW Macro Programming Guide to find a solution, but according to the guide I am doing everything correctly.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim excelApp As Object

    excelApp = CreateObject("excel.application")

    Dim corelApp As CorelDRAW.Application

    corelApp = CreateObject("CorelDRAW.Application")


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is your app set to "Any CPU"?

Comment: Yes. I double checked this just a minute ago.

Comment: Well, it should not :) It should be set to x86

Comment: Still getting the same exception. As a side question, is this because of the 32-bit dependencies?

Comment: Okay. Then no idea.. sorry

Comment: This is an obvious question, but is CorelDraw installed on the target computer?  You can build against the interops successfully and still not be able to run if CorelDraw is not installed.  If it is, have you looked up and verified that "CorelDRAW.Application" is in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Have you looked at the CLSID for CorelDRAW,Application and then looked and verified that there is a valid LocalServer32 registry key with a valid value?

Comment: It is installed on this PC. However, your comment had me look in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to find out that CorelDRAW.Application has to have the program number on the end of it as I have multiple versions of Corel on this PC. "CorelDRAW.Application" is now "CorelDRAW.Application.16" and the app is able to create the object. Thank you so much. If you add this as an answer I will totally upvote it.